# Running to Selects and grouping results with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to display a row of data from my main table (parents details) and then under each of those rows display the children's names from another table. I have had a go using the following code:

```
$sql="select distinct members_main.first_name as main_firstname,
    members_main.first_name as main_firstname,
    members_main.last_name as main_lastname,
    members_main.address_1 as main_address_1,
    members_main.address_2 as main_address_2,
    members_main.address_3 as main_address_3,
    members_main.address_4 as main_address_4,
    members_main.post_code as main_post_code,
    members_main.home_tel as main_home_tel,
    members_main.mobile as main_mobile,
    members_main.home_email as main_home_email
    from members_main, members_family where members_main.contact_id=members_family.contact_id";

$sql2="select members_family.first_name as fam_firstname,
    members_family.last_name as fam_lastname
    from members_family, members_main 
    where members_main.contact_id=members_family.contact_id";

$result=mysql_query($sql);

while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){

echo '<table width="100%"  cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<th align="left" valign="top">First Name</th>
<th align="left" valign="top">Last Name</th>
<th align="left" valign="top">Address 1</th>
<th align="left" valign="top">Address 2</th>
<th align="left" valign="top">Address 3</th>
<th align="left" valign="top">Address 4</th>
<th align="left" valign="top">Post Code</th>
<th align="left" valign="top">Home Tel</th>
<th align="left" valign="top">Mobile</th>
<th align="left" valign="top">Email</th>
</tr>';

echo '<tr>
<td valign="top">'.$rows['main_firstname'].'</td>
<td valign="top">'.$rows['main_lastname'].'</td>
<td valign="top">'.$rows['main_address_1'].'</td>
<td valign="top">'.$rows['main_address_2'].'</td>
<td valign="top">'.$rows['main_address_3'].'</td>
<td valign="top">'.$rows['main_address_4'].'</td>
<td valign="top">'.$rows['main_post_code'].'</td>
<td valign="top">'.$rows['main_home_tel'].'</td>
<td valign="top">'.$rows['main_mobile'].'</td>
<td valign="top">'.$rows['main_home_email'].'</td>
</tr>';

$result2=mysql_query($sql2);

echo '<table width="100%"  cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<th align="left" valign="top">First Name</th>
<th align="left" valign="top">Last Name</th>
</tr>';

while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result2)){

echo '<tr>
<td valign="top">'.$rows['fam_firstname'].'</td>
<td valign="top">'.$rows['fam_lastname'].'</td>
</tr>';

}

}

echo "</table>";
```

I am getting all rows from the members_family table per each record from the members_main. There can be more than one record in the members_family which will be associated to one record in the members_main. Bascially, members_main (parent) can have multiple children in the members_main.

Comment: your $sql2 needs to be within your primary while(){} as it'll require an input from your first while to select only the children for that parent

Comment: Thanks Dave. How do I do that? I am a PHP newbie!

Comment: `$sql2="select members_family.first_name as fam_firstname,
    members_family.last_name as fam_lastname
    from members_family
    where contact_id=".$rows['contact_id'];`  something like this just above your `$result2=` bit and you'll need to make sure you pull the contact_id out on your primary sql query.

Comment: Your first query is incorrect = duplicate column-names. Try to execute the query in your sql-client.

Comment: since you mention that you're a newbie in PHP, I think it's important that you are made aware that the `mysql_xxx()` functions are considered obsolete. If you're writing new code, it is strongly recommended that you use one of the more up-to-date database libraries -- either mysqli or PDO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just need to retrieve your `members_main.contact_id` from first table to use later in second `while` loop. Then you will have to move your second query inside first query `while loop` so the code will look like that:

```
$sql="select distinct 
members_main.contact_id as ID,
members_main.first_name as main_firstname,
members_main.first_name as main_firstname,
members_main.last_name as main_lastname,
members_main.address_1 as main_address_1,
members_main.address_2 as main_address_2,
members_main.address_3 as main_address_3,
members_main.address_4 as main_address_4,
members_main.post_code as main_post_code,
members_main.home_tel as main_home_tel,
members_main.mobile as main_mobile,
members_main.home_email as main_home_email
from members_main, members_family where members_main.contact_id=members_family.contact_id";

$result = mysql_query($sql);
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

//script goes on with table printing untill
<td valign="top">'.$rows['main_home_email'].'</td>
</tr>';
```

Now it's time for the query

```
$sql2="select members_family.first_name as fam_firstname,
members_family.last_name as fam_lastname
from members_family, members_main 
where members_main.contact_id=members_family.contact_id and members_main.contact_id = '".$rows['ID']."'";
```

As you see i added in `WHERE` condition to limit result for specified `ID` wich i retrieved from first query. Now you can print the rest of the table. Oh and by the way you closing table should look like that

```
echo "</table></td></tr></table>";
```

This is because you opened two tables.

Then I would like you to remember that `mysql_*` functions are deprecated so i would advise you to switch to [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: I've just deleted my post as it's very similar to yours.

Comment: Now that you've added the mysqli migration information, you can have an Upvote :D

Comment: @user2281899 you welcome dude, don't forget to upvote answer!

Comment: Just done it. Here's another one for you - where do I place a <hr> horizontal line in order to split the records up? Tried all over and cant get it right.

Comment: @user2281899 try to change to this echo "</table></td></tr><tr><td><hr></td></tr></table>";

Comment: @Fabio didn't work im afraid. It stuck the line at the bottom of the page under all records.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29846/discussion-between-fabio-and-user2281899)

Answer (score 0):

I feel some confusion with your second query. I am thinking that you have to construct your second query with the contact_id which is coming from first query(members_main). I assumes in that way and i have coded below. May be it will help you

```
        <?php
        $sql = "select distinct members_main.first_name as main_firstname,
            members_main.first_name as main_firstname,
            members_main.last_name as main_lastname,
            members_main.address_1 as main_address_1,
            members_main.address_2 as main_address_2,
            members_main.address_3 as main_address_3,
            members_main.address_4 as main_address_4,
            members_main.post_code as main_post_code,
            members_main.home_tel as main_home_tel,
            members_main.mobile as main_mobile,
            members_main.home_email as main_home_email
            from members_main, members_family where members_main.contact_id=members_family.contact_id";
        $result = mysql_query($sql);
        ?>
        <table width="100%"  cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
                <th align="left" valign="top">First Name</th>
                <th align="left" valign="top">Last Name</th>
                <th align="left" valign="top">Address 1</th>
                <th align="left" valign="top">Address 2</th>
                <th align="left" valign="top">Address 3</th>
                <th align="left" valign="top">Address 4</th>
                <th align="left" valign="top">Post Code</th>
                <th align="left" valign="top">Home Tel</th>
                <th align="left" valign="top">Mobile</th>
                <th align="left" valign="top">Email</th>
            </tr>
            <?php
            while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result))
            {
                $conId = $rows['contact_id']; //Which is comming from first Query
                $sql2 = "select members_family.first_name as fam_firstname,
            members_family.last_name as fam_lastname
            from members_family, members_main 
            where members_family.contact_id=$conId";

                $result2 = mysql_query($sql2);
                ?>
                <tr>
                    <td valign="top"><?= $rows['main_firstname']; ?></td>
                    <td valign="top"><?= $rows['main_lastname']; ?></td>
                    <td valign="top"><?= $rows['main_address_1']; ?></td>
                    <td valign="top"><?= $rows['main_address_2']; ?></td>
                    <td valign="top"><?= $rows['main_address_3']; ?></td>
                    <td valign="top"><?= $rows['main_address_4']; ?></td>
                    <td valign="top"><?= $rows['main_post_code']; ?></td>
                    <td valign="top"><?= $rows['main_home_tel']; ?></td>
                    <td valign="top"><?= $rows['main_mobile']; ?></td>
                    <td valign="top"><?= $rows['main_home_email']; ?></td>
                </tr>    

                <tr>
                    <td colspan="10">
                        <table width="100%"  cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0">
                            <tr>
                                <th align="left" valign="top">First Name</th>
                                <th align="left" valign="top">Last Name</th>
                            </tr>
                            <?php
                            while ($rowsFamily = mysql_fetch_array($result2))
                            {
                                ?>
                                <tr>
                                    <td valign="top"><?= $rowsFamily['fam_firstname']; ?></td>
                                    <td valign="top"><?= $rowsFamily['fam_lastname']; ?></td>
                                </tr>
                                <?php
                            }
                            ?>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <?php
            }
            ?>
        </table>
```